# Scale text size on Canvas

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm usint this class that provide to draw a cicle with inside a title and subtitle. the code is this (i'm not the author): https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar/blob/master/src/com/lylc/widget/circularprogressbar/example/CircularProgressBar.java . All works fine but when the subtitle text is more large it outside of the parent.. how can i scale this programmatically according to the screen resolutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check this out
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/
it has all of the methods in java in it. just look up the class of the object for the text and see if there is one.